# Show that if a function is not negative and its integral is $0$ than the function is $0$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Suppose $f$ is continuous, $f(x) \ge 0$ on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f(x) dx=0$. Show that $f(x)=0$ on $[a,b]$.

I know that if $f$ in continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0) > 0$, then there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t. $f(x) \ge \frac{1}{2} f(x_0)$ for $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and I think it should help me but I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: So what does that tell you about $\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} f(x) dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, let its anti derivative be $F$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$. As $f(x)\ge0$ on $[a,b]$, $F(x)$ is increasing on $[a,b]$.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx= F(b)-F(a)$$
So,
$$F(b)-F(a)=0$$
$$F(b)=F(a)$$
But $F$ is an increasing function on $[a,b]$. Thus, $F$ must be constant on $[a,b]$. Then,
$$F'(x)=f(x)=0$$
on $[a,b]$.