# How can we show that the equality doesn't occur?

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,1] \to [1,2]$, continuous on $[0,1]$ with $1<f(1)<2$.

Show that $$\int_0^1\left (f^2(x)-2f(x)\right )\, dx>-1.$$

We have that $$(f(x)-1)^2\geq 0\implies \int_0^1 (f(x)-1)^2\, dx\geq 0 \Rightarrow \int_0^1\left (f^2(x)-2f(x)\right )\, dx\geq -1.$$ Till here we have $\geq$ instead of $>$. How can we show that the equality doesn't occur?

Does the same holds also if $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: Think about it: Under which condition is $\int_0^1 (f(x)-1)^2\, dx = 0$?

Comment: If $f(x)=1$ but we know that $f(1)>1$ not that $f(x)>1$, or not? @MartinR

Comment: $f$ is continuous, so $\int_0^1 (f(x)-1)^2\, dx = 0$ would imply that $f(x)=1$ for *all* $x \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1729092.

Comment: Ahh I got it!! What if $f$ is Rieman integrable? Does something else hold in that case? @MartinR

Comment: Ahh I got it!! What if $f$ is Rieman integrable? Does something else hold in that case? @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Comment: You'd find the answer when you learn about Lebesgue's theory of integration.

Comment: Here is the corresponding result for Riemann-integrable functions: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/351196.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality occurs if and only if
$$\int_0^1 (f(x)-1)^2\, dx = 0 \iff \forall x\in(0,1), f(x)=1 \tag{1} $$
But because $f(1)>1$ and $f(x)$ continue, so there exists an interval $(1-\epsilon,1)$ near $1$ such that $\forall x \in (1-\epsilon,1), f(x)>1$.
Hence, the condition (1) can't be satisfied. That's why the equality doesn't occur.

Comment: Ahh I got it!! What if $f$ is Rieman integrable? Does something else hold in that case?

Comment: if $f$ is Riemann integrable. The equality can occur. The function $f(x)$ is equal to 1 for all $0\le x<1$ and $f(1) = 1.1$ for example.

Comment: I see!! Thanks for your help!! :-)